Execute a Perl script on a Vercel serverless function
My Node/Express backend is using a library (exiftool-vendored) that executes a Perl script. How can I have it running on my Vercel Serverless Function?
Server Logs:
Unhandled Rejection: Error: Perl must be installed. Please add perl to your $PATH and try again.

I have checked the documentation but couldn't find anything related to installing it.

Are you using Vercel or AWS? Could you clarify what are you trying to run where?

@AllanChua I'm using Vercel to host my Express.js backend. The backend needs to run a Perl script, but since Perl is not automatically installed on Vercel, I was wondering if it is possible to add.

Are you asking how to install Perl? On what kind of system?

@ikegami "The backend needs to run a Perl script, but since Perl is not automatically installed on Vercel, I was wondering if it is possible to add."

So yes? Again, what system (OS and distro)?
